# UI performance measurement for Android hybrid app

Tags: android, performance, webview, android-webview, frame-rate

**Objective**

I want to measure UI performance of my Android application which is a hybrid app. I am able to measure the performance correctly for native views. But, for web views, the numbers are unreliable. Looking for a way to measure UI performance reliably for native/web/hybrid apps.

Note: For debugging janky frames, we use Android studio CPU profiler / Perfetto. But, the nature of my product compels me to measure UI perf on every commit. So, profiler or measuring in debug app is not an option for such faster feedback.

**Metrics to be tracked for UI performance:**

Frame Rate
Janky Frames %ge
Continuous Frame drops

**Approach #1: dumpsys gfxinfo + FrameStats**

Reset gfxinfo and run automated test and at end measure gfxinfo. Get Janky frames % and fps for 95th and 99th %ile

Pros:

This gives Janky Frames %ge and FPS
It gives the right data for Native views
This works for Release builds as well

Cons:

It doesn't give reliable data for webview. Often, I get fps for 95th %ile below 10fps and Janky frames percentage as high as 90% even though the app UI appears to be smooth. When I compare the same flow using Chrome Devtools, it shows fps as 45 fps. Since mine is a hybrid app, I am getting completely incorrect performance metrics

**Approach #2: Jetpack jankstats**

- the numbers are very close to chrome devtools

challenges

- lot of frame duration are 0 ,1 ,2 ms
- When i use high end device (good CPU/GPU/RAM/120 Hz refresh rate) the frame rate goes till 500 fps. the way i calculate fps is  1000/ (sum of duration of all frames/ total frames). so this again becomes unreliable as it shows fps as 500

**Approach #3: Choreographer.FrameCallback**

- Here the frame duration numbers looks better. It shows all frames taking >=8ms and the numbers appear to be theoritically correct (i.e) for a phone with 120Hz display refresh rate, the fps is under 120. But, I am not sure about the correctness.

```
var choreographer = Choreographer.getInstance()
    var startTime: Long = 0
    var frameCallback: Choreographer.FrameCallback = object : Choreographer.FrameCallback {
        override fun doFrame(frameTimeNanos: Long) {
            if (startTime == 0L) {
                startTime = frameTimeNanos
            } else {
                val durationMs: Long = (frameTimeNanos - startTime) / 1000000
                // record duration
                LOG.i("choreographer log: $durationMs ms")
                startTime = 0
            }
            choreographer.postFrameCallback(this)
        }
    }
```

**Questions**

1. What is the is most reliable or right way to measure UI performance of hybrid apps?
2. Often, the fps is in the range of 20-30 but to human eyes(perceived performance), the app looks smooth. Is this acceptable?
3. What is right way to determine and flag UI performance basis the numbers ? 95/99th %ile fps or janky frames% or combination of both or continuous janky frames ( 5 continuous janky frames  or 1 frame taking more than 80 ms ) ? what is the reliable way to say that there can be a potential bad UI experience